# How to set custom WebLink field value when submit a defect by Rally rest .net api?

Tags: .net, rest, rally

I've configured a custom weblink field for defect in Rally. And i would like to use Rally rest .net api to submit new defect with value of custom weblink field accordingly to Rally.

Unluckily that weblink instance needs LinkID and DisplayString value, i don't know how to initiate a weblink instance to set for the field of defect.

I also have tried to set a DynamicJsonObject which is supported by Rally rest .net api to that field but it still failed.

The debugging screenshot
[image]

Please help!

**Edited:**

I've tried posting defect with the sample code as below:

```
        var api = new RallyRestApi("<myusername>", "<mypassword>", "https://community.rallydev.com");

        var defect = new DynamicJsonObject();
        defect["Name"] = "Sample Defect";
        defect["Description"] = "Test posting defect with weblink type field";
        defect["Project"] = "https://trial.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.29/project/5839639589.js";
        defect["SubmittedBy"] = "https://trial.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.29/user/5797741589.js";
        defect["ScheduleState"] = "In-Progress";
        defect["State"] = "Open";
        defect["Severity"] = "Major Problem";
        defect["Priority"] = "High Attention";
        defect["CustWebLink"] = new DynamicJsonObject(new Dictionary<string, object> 
        {
            {"DisplayString", "abc"},
            {"LinkID", "123"}
        });

        CreateResult creationResult = api.Create("defect", defect);
```

And now the defect is able to be posted to Rally, but not have value of CustWebLink. While investigating i see the CustWebLink field was ignored in serialization of posting request.

```
  Rally.RestApi Post Response: {"CreateResult": {"_rallyAPIMajor": "1", "_rallyAPIMinor": "29", "Errors": [], "Warnings": ["Ignored JSON element defect.CustWebLink during processing of this request."],.....}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is relatively straightforward, you just need to create separate DynamicJsonObject for the Weblink, and assign values to it for the LinkID and DisplayString attributes. Then, assign the Weblink object as a Field for the Defect. Here's a simple example:

```
    //Set our Workspace and Project scopings

    String workspaceRef = "/workspace/5912034914";
    String projectRef = "/project/5912035004";

    DynamicJsonObject myDefect = new DynamicJsonObject();
    DynamicJsonObject myWeblink = new DynamicJsonObject();

    // Populate the Weblink
    myWeblink["LinkID"] = "123456";
    myWeblink["DisplayString"] = "External Image Link";

    // Populate the Defect
    myDefect["Name"] = "My Defect";
    myDefect["Priority"] = "Normal";
    myDefect["Workspace"] = workspaceRef;
    myDefect["Project"] = projectRef;
    myDefect["zWeblinkField"] = myWeblink;

    CreateResult createDefect = restApi.Create("Defect", myDefect);
```

Comment: Thanks @Mark, I did the same way as yours, but it still keep raising the error of KeyNotFoundException.
    `Rally.RestApi Post Response: {"CreateResult": {"_rallyAPIMajor": "1", "_rallyAPIMinor": "29", "Errors": ["Cannot parse input stream due to I/O error as JSON document: Parse error: Read unexpected character 'R' while trying to read a property value. [ chars read = >>>{"defect":{"Name":"sdf","Description":"abc","Project":"xxx","SubmittedBy":"xxx","Priority":"High Attention","ScheduleState":"Completed","State":"Open","CusWebLink":R<<< ]"], "Warnings": []}}`

Comment: Hi Triet, based on the error string above, do you have an assignment statement that looks like:

myDefect["CusWebLink"] = ...;  ?

Is this being set to another DynamicJSON object corresponding to a Weblink? Note that the Weblink field doesn't contain any URL information itself - that's an attribute inside Rally. It should only contain a numeric identifier for LinkID, and a DisplayString.

Also note that you'll need to "escape" any special characters such as: \ / " ' < > etc. inside any strings you pass to a DynamicJSONObject or they may not get serialized correctly.

Comment: Hi Mark, i updated my question with attached debugging screenshot. You could see that CusWebLink field is assigned an DynamicJsonObject which has only 2 fields (LinkID and DisplayString). Both LinkID and DisplayString have string values.

Comment: Triet - thanks for the screenshot, that is helpful. I agree your weblink looks fine. I'm wondering though if it's a red herring for the issue you're experiencing. I'm noting that your Description field contains a lot of markup - which I'm guessing may be mis-handled when serialized by the DynamicJSONObject. A couple of things: Can you try a simple description i.e. "ABC123" and see if the update succeeds? If so, this may be a matter of needing a function that "escapes" the markup characters in your description. Otherwise - does the update succeed fine with no Weblink assigned at all? Thanks.

Comment: Mark, i updated the question with a new try as your suggestion, but nothing better than before. Besides, i just met problem with Weblink field, anything else is working fine.

Comment: Triet, thanks for the excerpt. I did notice that your screenshot calls the field: "CusWebLink" and your code snippet "CustWebLink". Which is the field name in Rally? Does your simplified excerpt work with "CusWebLink"?

Comment: I found the cause of issue. Instead of creating new DynamicJsonObject for defect and assigning directly field value into defect instance, i created a defect by passing a IDictionary<string,object> to constructor of DynamicJsonObject. It works fine unless the value is not a DynamicJsonObject(weblink value). The reason is weblink's DynamicJsonObject object has been casted into general object because using Dictionary<string,object>, then the serialization of rally rest.net api failed. I changed back to the way that constructs new defect first and assign field value directly, then it works.

Comment: Many thanks for your kind helps, Mark. The problem is solved.

Comment: Ah - thank you for this update Triet. I didn't do any testing with the Dictionary object, but I'm glad you found the issue!